# How can I call a Perl package I define in the same file?

Tags: perl, oop

I need to define multiple modules in the same file. I would like to do something like the following:

```
package FooObj {
    sub new { ... }
    sub add_data { ... }
}

package BarObj {
    use FooObj;
    sub new { 
        ... 
        # BarObj "has a" FooObj
        my $self = ( myFoo => FooObj->new() );
        ...
    }
    sub some_method { ... }
}

my $bar = BarObj->new();
```

However, this results in the message:

> Can't locate FooObj.pm in @INC ...
> BEGIN failed...

How do I get this to work?

Comment: The hint is in the error here:  "Cannot locate FooObj.pm".  .pm always means a file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Drop the `use`.  Seriously.

`use` tells perl to read in the code from another file, which you don't need to do because the code is in the same file.

Comment: And how to import anything exported by `Exporter` without the use of `use`?

Comment: @ceving Call `import` directly.  e.g., `FooObj->import(@params)` in the case of this question's code (if it used `Exporter`).

Comment: No I had a different question in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33634898/402322

Comment: How do I accomplish `use parent 'FooObj';` in the same case?

Comment: @Jean - Perl inheritance is implemented by way of the package-level `@ISA` array. `use parent` combines `use` and setting `@ISA` into a single operation, so, if you don't need the `use`, you can just set `our @ISA = qw(FooObj);` for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was trying to stay away from modifying `@ISA` according to latest Perl recommendation. So in this case I will have to or resort to putting each package in its on file?

Comment: @Jean - I stand corrected. I checked `perldoc parent` (http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) so I could give you a reference showing that it's the same thing, but spotted a sentence I'd never noticed before: "_If you want to have a subclass and its parent class in the same file, you can tell `parent` not to load any modules by using the `-norequire` switch_" So there you go - you _can_ `use parent` for modules within a single file after all!

Answer (score 17):

Unless I'm trying to create a private package that no one should know about, I put one package per file. That solves the problem. But, let's put them in the same file.

The [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) loads a file and calls the `import` method in that package. It's really only incidently that its argument looks like a module name. It's looking for the file. If the file is not there, it barfs.

You can do this, where `BarObj` assumes that `FooObj` is already there:

```
{
    package FooObj;
    sub new      { bless { _count => 0 }, $_[0] }
    sub add_data { $_[0]->{_count}++ }
}

{
    package BarObj;
    use Data::Dumper;

    sub new {
        bless { myFoo => FooObj->new }, $_[0];
        }

    sub foo         { $_[0]->{myFoo} }
    sub some_method { print Dumper( $_[0] ) }
}

my $bar = BarObj->new;
$bar->some_method;
```

If you need to interact with a package (and that's all it is: not a module or an object), you just need to have it defined before you want to use it. If you need to import something, you can call the `import` directly:

```
FooObj->import( ... );
```

Suppose there's something from `FooObj` that you want to import (but not inherit!), you call `import` directly with no loading;

```
{
    package FooObj;
    use Data::Dumper;
    sub new      { bless { _count => 0 }, $_[0] }
    sub add_data { $_[0]->{_count}++ }

    use Exporter qw(import);
    our @EXPORT = qw(dumper);
    sub dumper   { print Dumper( $_[0] ) }
}

{
    package BarObj;
    FooObj->import;

    sub new {
        bless { myFoo => FooObj->new }, $_[0];
        }

    sub foo         { $_[0]->{myFoo} }

    # dumper mixin, not inherited.
    sub some_method { dumper( $_[0] ) }
}

my $bar = BarObj->new;
$bar->some_method;
```

Answer (score 12):

By convention we put one package in one file and name them the same thing, but that is just for convenience.  You can put multiple packages in a single file.  Since they are already loaded, you do not need to use `use`.

You also do not need to create special scoping for the packages, as the package keyword takes care of that.  Using the braces does help with scoping of `our` variables.  So you don't strictly need those brace blocks, but they're a good idea.

`use` uses a package naming convention to find the appropriate file to load.  The `package` keyword inside the module defines the namespace.  And the import functions handle the package loading (generally inherited from Exporter).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package FooObj;

sub new
{
        my $this  = shift;
        my $class = ref($this) || $this;
        my $self  = {};
        bless $self, $class;
        $self->initialize();
        return $self;
}

sub initialize { }
sub add_data   { }

package BarObj;

#use FooObj; <-- not needed.

sub new
{
        my $this  = shift;
        my $class = ref($this) || $this;
        my $self  = { myFoo => FooObj->new() };
        bless $self, $class;
        $self->initialize();
        return $self;
}
sub initialize  { }
sub some_method { }
sub myFoo       { return $_[0]->{myFoo} }

package main;
use Test::More;
my $bar = BarObj->new();
isa_ok( $bar,        'BarObj', "bar is a BarObj" );
isa_ok( $bar->myFoo, 'FooObj', "bar->myFoo is a FooObj" );
done_testing();

__DATA__

ok 1 - bar is a BarObj isa BarObj
ok 2 - bar->myFoo is a FooObj isa FooObj
1..2
```

Comment: +1 For interesting info, however I still prefer using the braces as I think it adds visual clarity.

Comment: Robert, I see your point.  I often use (named) bare braces for visual clarity -- usually just before I decide that a given section needs to be refactored into its own routine or that a driver script needs to move more functionality back to the module.


I don't often put multiple packages in a single file, so haven't really considered the need to brace or not to brace.

Comment: It's not only clarity, but it's a scoping issue. Packages do not create a scope, so that my() variable you have there is file scoped without the braces that would limit it otherwise.

Comment: `our` variables will also become file scoped without braces around the package.  `package A; our $DEBUG = 'A'; package B; print $DEBUG;` prints 'A'