# How to write an importer for subs in Perl?

Tags: perl, import

I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

{
  package MSG;
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  sub info
  {
    print STDERR join("\n", @_), "\n";
  }

  sub import
  {
    no strict 'refs';
    *{caller().'::info'} = \&info;
  }
}

{
  package main;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  MSG->import;
#  sub info;

  info "a", "b";
}
```

Without the `sub info;` line in the `main` package, I get the following error:

```
String found where operator expected
```

I think the reason is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994023/402322). When I add the line, the code works as expected. But I do not want it in the `main` package.

How to move whatever `sub info;` does into the `import` function of the `MSG` package?

Comment: Note that this will work if you use parens: `info("a", "b");`, but like @ikegami said, most people use Exporter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter).

```
BEGIN {
  package MSG;

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use Exporter qw( import );
  our @EXPORT = qw( info );

  sub info {
    print STDERR join("\n", @_), "\n";
  }
}

{
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  BEGIN { MSG->import; }

  info "a", "b";
}
```

The `BEGIN` around `import` ensures the symbol is imported before `info` is compiled. It would be cleaner to use `use`, which is possible using small change.

```
BEGIN {
  package MSG;

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use Exporter qw( import );
  our @EXPORT = qw( info );

  sub info {
    print STDERR join("\n", @_), "\n";
  }

  $INC{"MSG.pm"} = 1;
}

{
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use MSG;

  info "a", "b";
}
```

Comment: Ok the second does it. Thanks!

Comment: The Exporter does not make any difference. The `$INC{"MSG.pm"} = 1;` which makes it possible to say `use MSG` makes the difference. The first solution is simply wrong.